# Automted UI Test with UTAM and Webdriver - UTAM Generator effort to create JSON Page Objects

Tags: test-automation, selenium, webdriver, utam

Introduction

> UI Test Automation Model (UTAM) is an open source solution built by
> Salesforce that lets you run E2E tests on any kind of app
> ([source](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/05/run-end-to-end-tests-with-the-ui-test-automation-model-utam))

The picture below is taken from [this blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/05/run-end-to-end-tests-with-the-ui-test-automation-model-utam)

[image: UTAM by salesforce]

I have a question regarding the [UTAM-Generator](https://utam.dev/tools/generator-start).

> UTAM Generator is a tool that generates UTAM JSON files from HTML
> files. An input HTML file can be either a raw HTML downloaded from a
> browser or a Web Component source code in HTML format, such as a
> Lightning web component.

My understanding is that for custom ui elements (custom html snippets, pages, components) the utam generator has to be used to create the `JSON Page Objects`. This provides objects and methods to access DOM nodes (labels, form fields and so on) on the page under test.

1. Is the use of UTAM generator a simple step - do you just point it to the source folder of all your custom pages and it generates all json page objects needed?
2. What are your experience setting this up is it easy, reliable?
3. Our Salesforce App has many time delayed loads. Our current tests with another testing tool do not run smoothly all the time. Has UTAM combined with webdriver similar issues?
4. Are there any steps needed while writing the html code that improve the creation or reliability of the `page objects` to access the `DOM node`
5. Is the backend code (the apex code) irrelevant for the testing? I assume that the backend-code is not relevant since the ui-test `E2E-test` only needs the expected output for a given input and therefore the apex code is not relevant.